# recursively compare the contents of 2 directories in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, terminal, rhel, directory, diff

A build process in an app is generating a directory structure in a CentOS 7 machine.  I have copied the app to a second location in the same server, made a few changes, and then run the build process again.  I want to compare results of the build processes.  **What specific commands need to be typed into the terminal in order to recursively compare all the nested directories and files within the directories created by each build process?**

I want to see:
1.) Which files are only in `Directory1` but **NOT** in `Directory2`
2.) Which files are only in `Directory2` but **NOT** in `Directory1`

`Directory1` is: `/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist`
`Directory2` is: `/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist`

Here is what I typed so far, which seems to be giving the same results in both directions, which would seem to be wrong:

```
[user@localhost angular2_oauth_seed_app]$ diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist | grep /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/boot.js /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/boot.js
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/boot.js.map /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/boot.js.map
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/index.html /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/index.html
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/vendor.js.map /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/vendor.js.map
[user@localhost angular2_oauth_seed_app]$ diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist  /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist | grep /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/boot.js /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/boot.js
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/boot.js.map /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/boot.js.map
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/index.html /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/index.html
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/vendor.js.map /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/vendor.js.map
[user@localhost angular2_oauth_seed_app]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you are seeing there are present in both directories but are *different*; that's why they show up.

If you run one of those `diff` commands you can see what it thinks are different

eg

```
diff -r /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/vendor.js.map /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/vendor.js.map
```

If you want to see files that are in one and not the other then the line begins with `Only in`

So in this simple tree:

```
$ mkdir X Y
$ touch X/1 Y/2
$ echo a file > X/a
$ echo different > Y/a
$ echo same > X/b
$ echo same > Y/b
```

We have files that are present in one directory but not the other, a file that is present in both but is different, and a file present in both that is the same.

```
$ diff -r X Y
Only in X: 1
Only in Y: 2
diff -r X/a Y/a
1c1
< a file
---
> different
$
```

We can see it's reported on the two unique files, and the file that has changed.  The file that is identical is not reported on.

Comment: OK.  So if I want to see what is different in both versions of each of those named files, how can I?  I hesitate to just open them up in two `gedit` windows because the files are huge.

Comment: That's what the `<` and `>` lines are in the output; the difference between them.

Comment: I do not think that we are understanding each other.  I want to know what is different in each version of `boot.js`, for example.

Comment: That _is_ what is shown on those lines.  In this example it's letting me that X/a and Y/a are different; the line that is difference is in line 1 and that it says `a file` in the first and `different` in the second.  `diff -r` does this for every file in the two trees and reports on those differences.  If you want the output in a different form then `diff -cr` will produce some _context_ around the lines. ("context diff")

Comment: In your answer, `X`, `Y`, `a`, and `b` have no meaning for me.  Can you express it in terms of what those variables actually represent.  So that, for example, I can see how to compare the file in `first/path/to/boot.js` with the file in `second/path/to/boot.js` to see what is different in the two files.

Comment: They're not variables, they're files and directories and I _show_ in the answer how they are generated and built (the `mkdir` and `echo` commands).  You can run those commands on your machine and see the results.

Comment: Here is what I do not understand: Does `X`= `/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/boot.js`, and does `Y` equal `/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/dist/client/boot.js`?  If so, what are `a` and `b`, and how do your `X/a` expressions actually look when there are already so many `/`'s floating around?

Comment: I created a simple minimal example showing the various outputs of `diff`.  Two directories, 3 files in each directory, with known content.  Play with my example and that'll help you understand the results of your more complicated setup.   It's a good way to learn; start with a simple setup and then go more complex.  So _forget_ your nodejs stuff, and start with this simple case.  Experiment in that.

Comment: `md X Y` results in `bash: md: command not found...`, and then `yum install nd` results in `No package md available`

Comment: Sorry, `md` is an old old old alias I have from DOS days for `mkdir`; answer updated!

Comment: I feel that you wrote something that is so heavily encoded that a person already needs to know the answer before they can decipher your example.

Comment: `X` and `Y` are directories.  But no one knows what `a` and `b` are.  And no one knows what `X/a`, `Y/a`, `X/b`, or `Y/b` are.  A you willing to explain?

Comment: They are files.  They could be called `node.js` or `foobarbaz` or `anythingyoulike.js` - they're just simple example files.

Comment: `touch X/1 Y/2` creates two files.  But all your other commands are nested, and thus more complicated that simply `echo` means print to console.  Can you please put a description next to each line of code that you wrote?  Learners who find this later will not be able to decipher it otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: `echo` means `send to OUTPUT`; the `>` means 'send output to file'.  So `echo hello > X/a` means "put the word hello info file called X/a".  This is basic Unix 101.  FWIW, DOS and Windows work the same way.  It's the basics of Unix input/output and you need to learn this before doing anything more complicated because you will see this sort of structure in almost _every_ answer.   I strongly recommend getting a "beginning Unix" type book or take a course.

Comment: I am marking this as accepted.  But please, still consider that sites like this are largely used by self-learners.  Lots of users are software developers or hobbyists, or even kids who read a few tutorial sites and then google problems that they encounter as they learn by doing.  If you are willing to summarize these comments in a revised version of your answer, those types of users will be better served when they read this latter, and you and I can each delete all of our comments here.